# Orchard shape tracing custom forms

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to learn Orchard and I ran into some things that confused me. I made a video and I'm hoping someone will explain what is happening in it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INAXTB8JxXM

When I click on "Create alternate template" for a piece of content in my site, nothing happens. But when I click the same thing for customer form, a field in a custom form disappears, and there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at how alternates work: [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) 
Check the View folder in you theme to see what have you created. There was a little of trigger happy going on there. 

When you are in the Editor select the uppermost part of the section you like to create an alternate and check the "Template" and "HTML". 

Everytime you create a new alternate, go and view it in your Views folder and keep drilling down into it to fine tune.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid mistake on my part. I understood that when I create alternate, a new template should be created. I did not see these new .cshtml files in Visual Studio project and was puzzled.
Files are being created, they are just not appearing in Visual Studio Themes folder.

Hope this will help some noob like me in the future. ;)